# Pegar dados tabela pivot Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Como eu posso pegar os dados da tabela pivot utilizando Laravel Eloquent?
Eu preciso saber qual `setor_id` do users e o `group_id` vinculado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca a parte do código dos Models onde vc fez os relacionamentos, fica mais fácil pra te ajudar. ;)

Comment: @luis-souza não está claro qual a sua dúvida. Por favor tente ser mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi, acho que é isso que você precisa. Deixei na forma padrão e também no eloquent

```
select ug.setor_id, setors.nome, ug.group_id, groups.descricao 
from users_groups_has_users as ug 
inner join groups on groups.id = ug.group_id  
inner join setors on setors.id = ug.setors_id  

$query = DB::table('users_groups_has_users')->join('groups', 'join groups on groups.id', '=', 'users_groups_has_users.group_id')->join('setors', 'join setors on setors.id', '=', 'users_groups_has_users.setor_id')
->select('ug.setor_id', 'setors.nome', 'ug.group_id', 'groups.descricao')->get()
```

Comment: Eloquent ou QueryBuilder?